# Gridview returning empty even when there is data. I want to use data in the gridview to update another database

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a webform that the user captures data. This data affects other data that is in a Gridview. I wanted to right a DetailsView type control that makes an Update button visible if data is change in textboxes and drop downs that would require a master data update.

I have a gridview on the form and when the user click on update I wanted to update all the rows in the databases using the primary key `OrderId` which is on the Gridview.

If I put the code being each textbox and dropdown box and that calls a routine called `DoUpdate` then this works. However it is a little slow since each change forces an update, so I thought it would be better to rather have an update button appear, and then the user can click that to do the update.

When the routine is called from the button routine though the gridview has no rows. I assume I either need to findcontrol (gridview) or something but have not idea what to find it in.

Here is the code that works when called in a behind button event, but the gridview returns row count 0 when called as part of the code behind button:

```
  List<string> _OrderIds = new List<string>();

  foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvOrderLines.Rows)
  {
    Label myOrderIDLablel = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblOrderID");    //find control since it is a template field
    _OrderIds.Add(myOrderIDLablel.Text);
  }
```

The gridview is defined in the ASP page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrderLines" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="odsOrderDetail"
```

Comment: Use GridViewCommandEventArgs and have a command name and action...see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.commandsource.aspx for more info

Comment: People get confused about grid views they exist to display data you want the underlining datasource to get the data I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above you may want to do something like:

```
List<string> _OrderIds = new List<string>();

  DataTable table = gvOrderLines.DataSource as DataTable;

  foreach (GridViewRow gvr in table.Rows)
  {
    Label myOrderIDLablel = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblOrderID");    //find control since it is a template field
    _OrderIds.Add(myOrderIDLablel.Text);
  }
```

I hope this get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi thansk for the answer I am getting nyull on the DataTable gvOrderlines is still null. So that is not working

Comment: How are you getting your gridview? Can you show code where you are getting the active gridview being used?

Comment: RE: GridViewCommandEventArgs how do I access this from a button control? The button is being pressed so I get the standard EventArgs

Comment: the data source is as follows:    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsOrderDetail" runat="server" 
    TypeName="TrackerDotNet.App_Code.OrderDetailDAL" SelectMethod="LoadOrderDetailData"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateOrderDetails" 
    StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRowIndex" 
    MaximumRowsParameterName="MaximumRows" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    DeleteMethod="DeleteOrderDetails" >

Comment: I think I have found the problem. The one tbx is a select parameter for the datasource. And that is also part of the data that I want to update. So the gridview datasource is not correct. I am going to have to make it a different parameter

Comment: I will have to make the select parameters session varaibles. Thank for the help looking at the datasource pointed me in the correct locaton.